# Is the confidence interval of f(x) equal to f( confidence interval(x))?

Tags: statistics

The problem is that I can only observe $X$ and calculate $f(X)$ analytically so I need to compute the confidence interval of $f(X)$ via $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if $f$ is monotonic. Then the probability of the interval is preserved.